# configuration file for web application deployment in multiple environments

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I'm building a web application using java I deployed it on Amazon Elastic beanstsalk tomcat environment. My problem is that before uploading the war file on the cloud I need to change all the pages links (for navigation from one page to another) in the JSPs as it differs from the links used when navigating locally.
I thought of making a configuration file to solve this annoying problem or add some lines in the Web.xml file but I don't know how to do so. 
Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pages were put in a separate folder that's why the application wasn't able to reach them..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have absolute urls like http://localhost:8080/link1/home.html and when you push your code to amazon the link would change to http://somedns/link1/home.html.

If yes you should use relative URLs instead of absolute URLS. i.e. instead of saying href = "http://localhost:8080/link1/home.html" you say href = "link1/home.html". This way your code does not get affected when you change environments.

Comment: actually the problem is that links are as follows: "myapp/home.html" but when pushed to amazon it should be: "/home.html" only